# how to strikethrough Japanese text using unicode characters

Tags: javascript, html, css, unicode

Please take a look at this jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/darrengates/c5mwohb7/

If you open the console in jsfiddle, you'll see that Japanese text does not "strikethrough" the same way that English does.

English strikethrough:
t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶E̶n̶g̶l̶i̶s̶h̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶t̶h̶r̶o̶u̶g̶h̶

Japanese strikethrough (on my screen just a bunch of rectangles with lines through):
の̶ス̶レ̶ッ̶ド̶で̶、̶ス̶ク̶リ̶ー̶ン̶シ̶

I'm hoping for some way to be able to strikethrough (without using  or other html tag-based method) of achieving strikethrough for Japanese and potentially other Asian languages.

Here's the code from the fiddle:

```
function strike(text) {
    return text
        .split('')
        .map((char) => {
            return char + '\u0336'
        })
        .join('')
}

console.log(strike('this is English strikethrough'))

console.log(strike('のスレッドで、スクリーンシ'))
```

Comment: I don't know if you are already aware, but [Wikipedia says (with my emphasis added)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikethrough): _"In Japan, **double strikethrough is conventionally used (rather than single strikethrough) when striking out text**. This is for added clarity, as in complex kanji a single strikethrough may be missed or confused with a stroke in the character"_. While that is not directly relevant to your problem, it does invite the question of why you are attempting to use single strikethrough rather than double strikethrough for Japanese characters.

Comment: It would also be helpful to clarify in your question _exactly_ what you expect to see when using strikethrough with Japanese characters. When the HTML `<p><s>のスレッドで、スクリーンシ</s></p>` is rendered the strikethrough works fine (for me), and goes right through the middle of the Japanese characters. Is that what you also want to see when using JavaScript instead, because even your English strikethrough is not doing that within your question, nor in Fiddle.

Comment: You can also get double strikethrough perfectly on Japanese characters in HTML: `<p><del style="text-decoration-style: double;">のスレッドで、スクリーンシ</del></p>`. Is that the rendering you should be trying to emulate in JavaScript?

Comment: I ended up simply using <del> instead of unicode for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear that there is a simple Unicode solution to this issue. Using HTML's  (or ) appears to be the best approach. As @skomisa noted in his comments, "text-decoration-style: double" is advisable when doing strikethrough with Japanese.